# Compile ptrace() program on OSX

Tags: c, macos, strace, ptrace

I have this simple C program on MacOS:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/ptrace.h>


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    pid_t pid = atoi(argv[1]);
    printf("pid = %jd\n", (intmax_t) pid);
    return ptrace(PT_ATTACHEXC, pid, 0, 0);
}
```

when I compile with gcc / cc, I get this error:

> ```
> In file included from my-waiter.c:4:
> /usr/include/sys/ptrace.h:99:38: error: unknown type name 'caddr_t'
> int     ptrace(int _request, pid_t _pid, caddr_t _addr, int _data);
>                                          ^
> 1 error generated.
> ```

does anyone know how to use `ptrace()` on OSX? I can't figure out how to get this to compile.

Comment: Include `<sys/types.h>` as well.

Answer (score 2):

`caddr_t` is BSD specific type which is defined in [`<sys/types.h`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=ptrace) header. It's not present in [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/).

Not quite relevant since you are on Mac OS. But on modern Linux systems that use glibc, it's exposed when `_DEFAULT_SOURCE` macro is defined. Systems having older glibc (older than glibc 2.20. `_BSD_SOURCE` has been deprecated since glibc 2.20) need to define `_BSD_SOURCE`.

Answer (score 2):

`man ptrace` gives:

```
PTRACE(2)                   BSD System Calls Manual                  PTRACE(2)

NAME
     ptrace -- process tracing and debugging

SYNOPSIS
     #include <sys/types.h>
     #include <sys/ptrace.h>

     int
     ptrace(int request, pid_t pid, caddr_t addr, int data);
```

then include `<sys/types.h>` as said.